# How to sort faster when adding few elements to sorted list?

Tags: sorting, tcl

I have a sorted list of ~10'000 elements in which I insert a few elements (1-10) at a time between popping the first. Measurements show the sort procedure take several milliseconds (~5), presumably because `lsort` makes a sort from scratch every time. It now takes up the majority of frame time so I need to do something about it.

Is there some trick to make merging a large sorted list with a small sorted list with enhanced efficiency?

Code for explaining the context:

```
while {true} {
  set work [lindex $frontier 0]
  set frontier [lreplace $frontier 0 0]
  if {[done $work]} break;
  set more_work [do work]; # about 1-10 elements, distribution is generally hard to predict
  lappend frontier {*}$more_work
  set frontier [lsort $frontier]; # when frontier is 10'000 elements time to sort is ~5ms
}
```

Trying my best to implement a Tcl proc doing merge-like sort, will post findings. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proc reduces time elapsed from ~5ms to ~1.2ms:

```
proc merge_insert {sorted1 sorted2} {
  set res {}
  set prevloc 0
  foreach insert $sorted2 {
    # find location of next element to insert
    set nextloc [lsearch -bisect -integer -index 1 $sorted1 [lindex $insert 1]]
    # append up to next loc
    lappend res {*}[lrange $sorted1 $prevloc $nextloc] $insert
    # put read location just beyond the inserted element
    set prevloc [+ 1 $nextloc]
  }
  # append whatever tail is left
  lappend res {*}[lrange $sorted1 $prevloc end]
  return $res
}
```

The attribute sorted on is an integer in the second element in each sorted element, hence the `-integer index 1` and `lindex $insert 1`.

Comment: The `lsort` command does a full merge sort every time; insertions like this are a better choice and `lsearch -bisect` is the tool for the purpose. Alas, there's still the real cost of doing the _actual_ inserts because Tcl lists are simple arrays under the covers and so require a heavy copy to insert…